# Make error bars in multiple excel charts transparent

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to make the error bars transparrent ... the code works to make the error bars transparent on a single chart on a single worksheet, but ideally I would like this to loop through multiple excel charts on different worksheets...

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim objCht As ChartObject

For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = -0.0500000119
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 1
    End With
Next objCht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one more loop for all the Worksheets. Something like this:

```
Dim objCht As ChartObject

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

   For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Select
      With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = -0.0500000119
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 1
      End With
   Next objCht

Next ws
```

Comment: should get rid of select/selection ....use   `With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line`

Comment: i know this, but that wasn't his Question and i didn't want to Confuse him with a lot of changes in his code he didn't ask for.

Comment: Thank-you for your help - the code works if I click on each sheet to activate, but is there a way to loop through all the worksheets?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Macro2
End Sub

Comment: @tj123 how do you mean this. do you need to activate the sheet so the code works fine? Then you just need to add 'ws.activate' before the second loop or do you want to run the code if you activate a sheet in the workbook?

Comment: @tj123 if you want to run the code whenever you change the sheet you need to insert on "ThisWorkbook" this code: `Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call Macro2
End Sub`

Comment: How would I remove the active chart selection?

Comment: objCht.Delete when you want to Delet it. ws.cells(1,1).select if you want to remove the selection but don't want to delete the Chart

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, there's no need to use `Select` :

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

' loop through sheets in this workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' loop through Chartobjects in sheet
    For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        ' no need to select the chart or the series use With statement instead
        With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
           .HasErrorBars = True
            With .ErrorBars.Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = -0.0500000119
                .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                .Transparency = 1
            End With
        End With
    Next objCht
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: do you need to set any of the properties other than Transparency ?  or did you actually mean semi-transparent?

Comment: @jsotola this is the answer I gave, I think you meant to post your comment on the post